# Ruby on Rails: "SELECT" MySQL command

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing an application using MySQL. There's a table called "Requests".

That table has a field "user_id" from Table "Users".

I'd like to select all requests from a `user_id`.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE user_id = ("the id I want");
```

How can I do that using Ruby language, and not an SQL string?

Answer (score 1):

In ActiveRecords its done like this:

```
Request.where(user_id: ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.find_by_user_id(USER-ID-YOU-WANT)
```

Or

```
Request.find_by user_id: 'USER-ID-YOU-WANT'
```

documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find)

Comment: `user_id` is not same as `id`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways, as you can see from @shivam and @amalrik's answers. It also depends on the ORM you're using. If you're using Rails out of the box, you're probably using [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

Probably the most idiomatic way is to have the correct [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) on your `User` and `Request` models.

in `app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests
end
```

and `app/models/request.rb`:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This would allow you to find a user and call its `#requests` method:

```
User.find(user_id).requests
```